# Pickle in multiprocessing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pickle, joblib

The goal of following code is merely to fill array a with 0 to 9:

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

inputs = range(10)
a = np.zeros(10)

def processInput():
    def testNested(t):
        a[t]= t
    Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores, backend="threading")(delayed(testNested)(t) for t in range(0, 10))

processInput()
```

I get the pickle error when I'm trying to call multiprocess in a function:

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'processInput.<locals>.testNested'
```

**Question:** Any suggestion how to achieve this goal, in a case I have to operate multiprocess within other functions?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the error message, [as the document stated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled), a nested function cannot be pickled, you should define worker function at the top level of a module.

Comment: The error message is only clear when you understand all the terms that it uses.

Comment: @problemofficer thanks for your advice, I have updated.

Answer (score 0):

There are examples shown in built-in [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) package, I slightly modified first one, which includes using [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) class:

> ***`class multiprocessing.pool.Pool([processes[, initializer[, initargs[, maxtasksperchild[, context]]]]])`***
>
> > A process pool object which controls a pool of worker processes to which jobs can be submitted. It supports asynchronous results with timeouts and callbacks and has a parallel map implementation.
> >
> > ***`processes`*** is the number of worker processes to use. If processes is `None` then the number returned by [`os.cpu_count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.cpu_count) is used.
> >
> > If ***`initializer`*** is not `None` then each worker process will call `initializer(*initargs)` when it starts.
> >
> > ***`maxtasksperchild`*** is the number of tasks a worker process can complete before it will exit and be replaced with a fresh worker process, to enable unused resources to be freed. The default `maxtasksperchild` is `None`, which means worker processes will live as long as the pool.
> >
> > ***`context`*** can be used to specify the context used for starting the worker processes. Usually a pool is created using the function `multiprocessing.Pool()` or the `Pool()` method of a context object. In both cases context is set appropriately.
> >
> > > **Note** that the methods of the pool object should only be called by the process which created the pool.

Therefore you don't really need to import and use [`joblib`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/joblib), because [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) uses `the number of CPUs in the system` by default:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as p:
        print(p.map(f, list(range(10))))
```

however same result could be achieved by writing "one-liner":

```
print(list(range(10)))
```

I mapped pool `p` to function `f()` in case you want to do something more complex than just assigning values to index.